# Rails: Cannot create object of class from initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, initialization, instance

This is my initializer:

```
puts 'running ...'
ObjectClass.new
puts 'finished'
```

In my terminal:

```
$ rails c
running ...
finished
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
irb(main):001:0> ObjectSpace.each_object(ObjectClass).select { |o| o }
=> []
irb(main):002:0> ObjectClass.new
=> #<ObjectClass:0x94c0650>
irb(main):003:0> ObjectSpace.each_object(ObjectClass).select { |o| o }
=> [#<ObjectClass:0x94c0650>]
```

How can I create an instance of `ObjectClass` from within my initializer file.

Comment: While the purpose is rather unclear and you definitely are doing it wrong, you might assign it’s value to some global variable like `$oc = ObjectClass.new`. That way it won’t be garbage collected.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ use `ObjectSpace.each_object(ObjectClass).to_a` instead of void redundant `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `ObjectClass.new` into `@var` or `@@var` or `$var`.

initializer:

```
class ObjectClass; end
$var = ObjectClass.new
```